# RAML: Specifying arbitrary queryParameters

Tags: raml

I'm trying to model a GET request in my RAML that has an arbitrary list of URL parameters. 2 parameters are known, but the remainder are name/value pairs that are chosen from the response data from other request types. I tried to use additionalParameters: true in my queryParameters list, but I get an error message from osprey-mock-service when it attempts to parse the RAML:

```
each query parameter must be a map
```

The relevant snippet from my RAML is:

```
/statistics:
  /{statisticId}:
      get:
        description: Get the stastic data
        queryParameters:
          start:
            displayName: Start Time
            type: integer
            description: The timstamp in milliseconds indicating the beginning of the collection of timeseries data
            example: 1380601800000
            required: false
          end:
            displayName: End Time
            type: integer
            description: The timstamp in milliseconds indicating the end of the collection of timeseries data
            example: 1380601800000
            required: false
          additionalParameters: true
        responses:
          200:
            body:
              application/json:
                schema: statistic
                example: !include ../dto/statistic.sample
```

The error message goes away when I remove the line:

```
      additionalParameters: true
```

I have not found a reference that indicates that you can use additionalParameters with queryParameters, but it seems to make sense that you could.

I don't necessarily need to resolve the error message, but I would like to have URL parameters like the following:

```
?start=23010030&end=23011470&content=abc.com&node=siteA
```

Where content and node are not predefined parameter names.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

`additionalParameters` is currently not supported by RAML: it is nowhere to be found in version [`0.8` of the specification](http://raml.org/spec.html).

This said, this (very important) topic is [under discussion in the RAML forums](http://forums.raml.org/t/allowing-arbitrary-query-parameters/91)

So for the moment, I see only two options:

- Do not specify these parameters, the caveat being that tools, like RAML Tester, will report request violations if you use these parameters.
- Specify all the possible parameters with `required: false`, the caveat being that you need to know all these parameters beforehand.